# Jquery Multidimentional array matching and returning parent array value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a simple question but still haven't found neither figured out out to solve this.

I have this array:

```
var charsAndTypes = [
    {'type': 'Power', 'characters': ['Bunny','Buffalo']},
    {'type': 'Magic', 'characters': ['Sheep','Dragon']},
    {'type': 'Sense', 'characters': ['Fox','Lion']},
    {'type': 'Charm', 'characters': ['Cat','Raccoon']}
];
```

I need to search for the "characters", like "Bunny", and then catch the "type" to save it to a var, tried .map(), .filter, foreach inArray, but stil didn't work has I wanted

Basicly I need a function like this in the end

```
function searchInArray ( array, string ){
    //search in characters what array contains that string
    //then return the array that has the value
}

var charType = searchInArray(charsAndTypes, "Bunny"); 

//then the output must be "Power" in this case
console.log(charType.type);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the array, and check if the object's array has the value.

```js
var charsAndTypes = [
    {'type': 'Power', 'characters': ['Bunny','Buffalo']},
    {'type': 'Magic', 'characters': ['Sheep','Dragon']},
    {'type': 'Sense', 'characters': ['Fox','Lion']},
    {'type': 'Charm', 'characters': ['Cat','Raccoon']}
];

function search (arr, char) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].characters.indexOf(char) > -1) {
      return arr[i].type;
    }
  }
}

console.log(search(charsAndTypes, 'Bunny'));
```

Comment: Ok, that was my problem, i was returning the whole array and then logging the typ that returned undefined, thanks a lot for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). It works like `filter` but only returns one value from the array, instead of an array of matches.

```
function search(arr, char)
  return arr.find(function(charAndType){
    return ~charAndType.characters.indexOf(char);
  });
}
```

It's ES6 and probably isn't cross-browser yet. There's a polyfill in that page though.

Answer (score 0):

One simple for loop. If it doesn't find it it will return undefined.

```js
var charsAndTypes = [
    {'type': 'Power', 'characters': ['Bunny','Buffalo']},
    {'type': 'Magic', 'characters': ['Sheep','Dragon']},
    {'type': 'Sense', 'characters': ['Fox','Lion']},
    {'type': 'Charm', 'characters': ['Cat','Raccoon']}
];


function searchInArray ( array, string ){
    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(array[i].characters.indexOf(string)>=0)
          return array[i];
    }
}

var charType = searchInArray(charsAndTypes, "Bunny"); 

//then the output must be "Power" in this case
console.log(charType.type);
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will do the trick.

```
function searchInArray ( arr, string ){
    var found = false;
    $.each(arr, function(k,v) {
        if (v.characters.indexOf(string) != -1) {
            found = v;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return found;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kywoxut6/

Answer (score 0):

```
var charsAndTypes = [
    {'type': 'Power', 'characters': ['Bunny','Buffalo']},
    {'type': 'Magic', 'characters': ['Sheep','Dragon']},
    {'type': 'Sense', 'characters': ['Fox','Lion']},
    {'type': 'Charm', 'characters': ['Cat','Raccoon']}
];

var search = function (arr, char) {
    for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        if (arr[index].characters.indexOf(char) > -1) {
            return arr[index];
        }
    }
}

var charType = searchInArray(charsAndTypes, "Bunny");
console.log(charType.type);
```